# i am trying to send a request with json parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

whats up!

i am trying to send a request with json parameters and i don't understand why in the server side
the parameter doesn't being send

```
let res = fetch("http://localhost:1000/vacations/" + vacation.id, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: { "Authorization": localStorage.token },
            body: { "picture": vacation.picture }
        })
```

i am trying to view the picture in the parameter in the server side

i use in node.js server the middleware express.json

and still i cant get this parameter :(

Comment: use post request for sending data ```{ method: 'POST', headers: { 'Authorization': localStorage.token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },  body: JSON.stringify(data) }```

Comment: yes that was my problem thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may send a stringify body using `JSON.stringify`.

```
  const res = fetch(`http://localhost:1000/vacations/${vacation.id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.token
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          picture: vacation.picture
      })
  })
```